# How to use locks/synchronization here

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this code block here and i need to make sure the `rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch` is synchronized between threads properly.  I was going to use `synchronize` but that i don't think will work here because of the variable being used in the `if` statement.  I read online about `final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();` but I am a bit confused on how to use it in this case properly with the `try/finally` block.  Can I get a quick example?  Thanks

```
// start synchronization
if (rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch.get(rankedType).size() >= 2) {
  Player player1 = rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch.get(rankedType).remove();
  Player player2 = rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch.get(rankedType).remove();
  // end synchronization
  // ... I don't want this all to be synchronized, just after the first 2 remove()
} else {
  // end synchronization
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You can also use Collection.synchronizedMap() or a map class from java.util.concurrent if the perform to your needs.

Comment: `but that i don't think will work here because of the variable being used in the if statement` why don't you synchronize the `if` also?

Comment: @DarthAndroid that would not help him at all. Multiple threads would be able to get past the `size() >= 2` check at the same time.

Comment: Why do you think `synchronized` wouldn't work with the `if` statement? You just wrap the `if` statement in a `synchronized ( rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch ) {...}` block. But of course that's only half the story because you need to synchronise **all** access to the shared object correctly. And the important word here is "correctly". In a multithreaded system, synchronisation must be an organic part of the design, not just an afterthought.

Comment: @iCode4Food check the edit, sorry i forgot to write something

Comment: Is `rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch` declared locally in the method ? I think you will need to show more details about `rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch` and its access level etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you want to do:

```
boolean has_players = false;
Player player1;
Player player2;
synchronize (rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch) {
  if (rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch.get(rankedType).size() >= 2) {
    player1 = rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch.get(rankedType).remove();
    player2 = rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch.get(rankedType).remove();
    has_players = true;
  }
}

if(has_players){
  // ... I don't want this all to be synchronized, just after the first 2 remove()
}
else{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Good idea!  This should do exactly what I need it to do.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to `synchronize` -- the one you want is...

```
boolean shortQueue = true;
synchronize (rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch) {     
  if (rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch.get(rankedType).size() >= 2) {
    shortQueue = false;
    Player player1 = rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch.get(rankedType).remove();
    Player player2 = rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch.get(rankedType).remove();
  } 
}
if (shortQueue) {
    // this was your else clause
} else {
    // this was the rest of the processing
}
```

The caveat is that you synchronize code blocks, not data (even though the goal is to protect data).  So you also need to also synchronize any other code areas that touch that variable, such as whatever code adds new players to the queue.

There are more complicated methods that will perform better, but this one will work and is easy to get correct.

Comment: My bad, can you check the edit I made.  I forgot a key piece of information.

Comment: This still makes the rest of his "if" clause synchronized, which he stated he did not want. Once you change that, your answer would become the same as mine.

Comment: I think you missed that fact that the question changed after I put in the initial answer.  Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

While the flag idea works, the least hacky solution is to rewrite the code.

```
private PlayerPair pickPlayers( Type rankedType ) {
  synchronized( rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch ) {
    if (rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch.get(rankedType).size() >= 2) {
      Player player1 = rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch.get(rankedType).remove();
      Player player2 = rankedPlayersWaitingForMatch.get(rankedType).remove();
      return new PlayerPair( player1, player2 );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And in your calling code...

```
PlayerPair pair = pickPlayers( rankedType );
if( pair != null ) { 
   ...do unsynchronised stuff here...
} else {
   ...more unsynchronised stuff
}
```

This is far more readable and easier to get correct.

Comment: This solution would be more fluent in a language with ad-hoc tuple support.  +1 for adding a new idea to the discussion.  The advantage of the code style here is that it encapsulates the concept if there are other places in the code that pick players in pairs. If that isn't likely, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @MelNicholson True, but this is what we've got to cook with :) What I've tried to convey really is what I'd already written in a comment: synchronisation should be an essential part of the design, otherwise you're bound to run into a nasty problem. I'm sure we've all tried the alternative, the temptation is very strong ("I'll just add a couple of synchronized's here and there and it'll be thread safe in no time."), I certainly have. And the lesson I learned was: don't. :)